# Eclipse Plugin: Hide Property Page from Help -> Installation Details -> Installed Software -> Properties

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've encountered a problem with my own property page for the plug-in.

I have "plugin.xml" file for my Eclipse plug-in with this extension:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
    <page class="com.myplugin.ProjectProperties"
          id="com.myplugin.propertyPages.ProjectProperties"
          name="Page Name">
       <filter name="nature"
               value="com.some.nature">
       </filter>
    </page>
 </extension>
```

It works if you open Properties on the projects with "com.some.nature" nature.

In addition to that it also shows my property page in `Help -> Installation Details -> Installed Software -> Properties` on every single installed plug-in. How do I "filter" it out from there?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include an `enabledWhen` element to restrict when the page is enabled.

For example:

```xml
<filter
      name="projectNature"
      value="org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature">
</filter>
<enabledWhen>
   <adapt
         type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
   </adapt>
</enabledWhen>
```

This is used by one of the Eclipse PDE pages to show the page when the project nature is the PDE nature and a project is the current selection.
Note that this is using `projectNature` for the filter name.

Alternatively some code just uses `enabledWhen` without using `filter`:

```xml
<enabledWhen>
   <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
      <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
            value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature"/>
   </adapt>         
</enabledWhen>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If this answers your question you should 'accept' it by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.